# Angular 2 material: Make cards in one line

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular2-material

I made a simple code here http://embed.plnkr.co/INpybaat2XZqdStsKAdy/. The cards didn't rendered in one line. How to make it rendered in one line? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

try `float: left;` in md-card css file. Like this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/INpybaat2XZqdStsKAdy?p=preview

Comment: I've tried it and works, but float change behavior how card rendered. This is what I mean. https://postimg.org/image/685zykbc5/

Comment: What exactly did you mean? I still don't understand.

Comment: Don't you see link to my image? I've shared a screen shot that both card rendered in the same line (as expected using float) but it change the height of the card (both card have different height). [link](postimg.org/image/685zykbc5)

Comment: I think if you don't want to use a container for cards. Just specified the height for them cause they will resize depend on their content

Comment: It's ok to use container, but it still have different behavior about card's height when use container and flexbox. Any suggestion, @cuongngo?

Comment: Could you add any example which different height card when use container with flex?

Comment: I've try solution by @JayChase this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/V0pegO?p=preview). Mesure height of the card with and without #card-container in css file. They've different height. I think the best answer is waiting for angular material 2 layout directive. For now, I prefer the answer by JayChase.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flexbox as the container for the cards.

```
<div id="card-container">
    <md-card class="short">
        <md-card-title-group>
        <img md-card-sm-image src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-surface-with-creases_1160-191.jpg">
        <md-card-title>Hi</md-card-title>
        <md-card-subtitle>Have a nice day</md-card-subtitle>
        </md-card-title-group>
    </md-card>
    <md-card>
        <md-card-title-group>
        <img md-card-sm-image src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-surface-with-creases_1160-191.jpg">
        <md-card-title>One</md-card-title>
        <md-card-subtitle>Is the first order in numeric</md-card-subtitle>
        </md-card-title-group>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

and for app.component.css

```
md-card {
max-width: 150px;
margin: 4px;
}

#card-container {
display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/V0pegO?p=preview

Comment: Hi @JayChase. Your answer is better than the first one, but it change a little bit about how browser render it. Try without your #card-container (of course it will appear in separate line) and measure the height of the card. It change the height of the card a little bit. Do you have any other suggestion how to make both card in the same line in appropriate way?

Comment: @ChristoforusSurjoputro add `align-items: flex-start;` to your `#card-container` style. The default value for `align-items` is "stretch" which will make all elements the same height.